# How to decrypt notepad++ nppcrypt encrypted message in programming language

Tags: kotlin, encryption, aes, bouncycastle, scrypt

plain text:Hello leon

password & iv:leon1234leon1234

cipher: rijndael cbc 128bits

nppcrypto encrypt info

```
<nppcrypt version="1016">
<encryption cipher="rijndael" key-length="16" mode="cbc" encoding="base64" />
<key algorithm="scrypt" N="16384" r="8" p="1" salt="HA==" />
<iv value="bGVvbjEyMzRsZW9uMTIzNA==" method="custom" />
</nppcrypt>
/8r4DGLVYC+YJSPMFQ8lFQ==
```

I use java BouncyCastle lib to test, but the encrypt result is diffent

related code is at my github repo

https://github.com/Leon406/Crypto/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/me/leon/modern/PBE.kt

nppcrypt plugin repo: https://github.com/jeanpaulrichter/nppcrypt

**Edit:** code here as well

```
package me.leon.modern

import com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtil
import me.leon.base64Decode
import me.leon.toBase64
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.BCrypt
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.KDF2BytesGenerator
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.SCrypt
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex

/**
 *
 *
 * https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html
 * https://antofthy.gitlab.io/info/crypto/key_derivation.txt
 * https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-kdf.html
 * key derivation function
 * SCrypt   BCrypt  PBKDF2    Added in OpenSSL 3.0
 * Question? how to interact notepad++ nppcrypto
 */
object PBE {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val pwd = "leon1234leon1234"
        val salt = "HA=="
        val ivbase64 = "leon1234leon1234"
        val key = SCrypt.generate(pwd.toByteArray(), salt.base64Decode(), 16384, 8, 1, 16).toBase64()
        val key2 = BCrypt.generate(pwd.toByteArray(), "iP/MuFEP/jgHs7lBGez7kg==".base64Decode(), 8).toBase64()
        println(key)

        SCryptUtil.scrypt(pwd,16384,8,1).also {
            println("scrypt $it")
        }
        //$s0$e0801$YzXui6dcQ0qbWnTBP36t+Q==$AW81b69h3HepUIi7pW7ThAKuDdpb1oZ7bFIJrF9zQzA=
        //$s0$e0801$bGvjR0//WiaHqAiSDi5Q9g==$8DzAr+nhUyW5fhdj3MLIpovRdp+dLfVoXGqN+Pp3kZU=
         SCrypt.generate(pwd.toByteArray(), "YzXui6dcQ0qbWnTBP36t+Q==".base64Decode(), 16384, 8, 1, 32).toBase64().also {
             println("scrypt dd $it" )
         }
        val r = SymmetricCrypto.encrypt(key, "Hello leon", ivbase64, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
            .also { println(it) }
        val r2 = SymmetricCrypto.encrypt(key2, "Hello leon", ivbase64, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
            .also { println(it) }

        SymmetricCrypto.decrypt(key, r, ivbase64, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding").also { println(it) }
        SymmetricCrypto.decrypt(key2, r2, ivbase64, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding").also { println(it) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the key to `SymmetricCrypto.decrypt()` Base64 encoded, but you do not perform Base64 decoding there, but UTF8 encoding, s. [here](https://github.com/Leon406/Crypto/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/me/leon/modern/SymmetricCrypto.kt#L100). For this reason the decryption fails.

Usually key and IV are binary data and not a string. Therefore both should be passed as `ByteArray` in `encrypt()/decrypt()`. If they are to be passed as a string, then a reliable binary-to-text encoding must be performed, such as Base64.

The following fix uses the second variant, i.e. passes to `decrypt()` a Base64 encoded key and IV and Base64 decodes both there:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.SCrypt
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
import java.security.Security
import java.util.*
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.SecretKey
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
...
val pwd = "leon1234leon1234"
val salt = "HA=="
val key = SCrypt.generate(pwd.toByteArray(), salt.base64Decode(), 16384, 8, 1, 16).toBase64().also { println(it) } // 6owLoTdeL67pEHxJ5gLY9Q==
val iv = "bGVvbjEyMzRsZW9uMTIzNA=="
val ciphertext = "/8r4DGLVYC+YJSPMFQ8lFQ=="
/*SymmetricCrypto.*/decrypt(key, ciphertext, iv, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding").also { println(it) } // Hello leon
...
fun decrypt(key: String, data: String, iv: String, alg: String): String {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(alg)
    val keySpec: SecretKey = SecretKeySpec(key.base64Decode()/*toByteArray()*/, alg.substringBefore("/")) // pass key Base64 encoded and Base64 decode here
    if (alg.contains("ECB".toRegex()))
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec)
    else
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, IvParameterSpec(iv.base64Decode()/*toByteArray()*/)) // pass iv Base64 encoded and Base64 decode here
    return String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(data)))
}
```

A few notes concerning security:

- Static IVs are insecure. *nppcrypt* supports random IVs. The IV should not be identical to the password.
- A 1 byte salt is too short.
- ECB is insecure (just for completeness, since ECB is not used in the posted example, but is implemented).

Comment: The demo I wrote can decrypt sucessfully.The Question is why the answer it not the same as notepad++ plugin encryted

Comment: I forget change ivbase64 name, it's not base64 encoded, and it indeed misleads you